# OpenCV 3.0.0 enums have changed where can I find an updated list?

Tags: c++, opencv, enums

I have been using OpenCV 2.48, but I was having trouble with loading certain video types so I have downloaded the most up to date source code and built myself. This has fixed the problems I was having with reading certain video files but as I now have OpenCV 3.0.0 all of the parameter enums seems to have changed completely. For example

2.4.8

```
Mat matTarget = imread(target, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

3.0.0

```
Mat matTarget = imread(target, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

Can anyone tell me where I can find a list of what all the original enums have changed to?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Online documentation is up to v2.4.8 so far. I guess you have to wait for a while for this.

Comment: there is http://docs.opencv.org/master/  , but no such thing as an overview for the enums

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0, too. I entrusted enums to my IDE, visual studio. Even if I don't know the exact name it can locate it.